Filter in T-SQL by many elements - efficient way
I want to use in where statement filter on many elements (over 100).
For filter on few elements I normally use IN:
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE Product IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

But what if there is over 100 products?

Use a table type. Continue to use an IN (as it allows 100+ values).

You can also load the list into a #temp table or @table variable and reference it in a condition like WHERE Product IN (SELECT SelectedProduct FROM @ProductList). A JOIN could also be used.

I suppose the question is, why do you think having 100+ values in your IN is a problem? It's true that including many values in an IN clause is documented to cause errors, but we're talking several hundred at least (and normally it's when you have a thousand or more). And even then, said documentation tells you what to do instead. So what are you confused about here?

The question also is, what is this part of? Where do you get those values? It's quite different if you have a previous select statement where you get the list, or if you have just a fixed list from some other source.

Where would the 100 product values come from? User input? Hard-coded application data? Another table? You may be able to use a JOIN or a subquery that only picks those values from another table instead of specifying all of them at once

In this case, we need to use subquery:
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE Product IN (SELECT Product FROM Product_table WHERE ... );

Hope it helps!
